# Setting up Python Virtual Env Initiating Jupyter Notebook gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When I try to Initiate Jupyter notebook in the virtual env, I get the following error - .gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Virtual Env -wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.0.7.tar.gz

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 251, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/home/vraja/pyspark/lib/python2.7/site- 
  packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 872, in _default_allow_remote
     for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, 
     socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
(pyspark)-sh-4.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set profile variable ?..

Please add below env variable in profile file.

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'

Comment: Yes I did set them

Comment: Follow this link ,  https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f

Comment: Changed NotebookApp.ip='*' to Changed NotebookApp.ip='0.0.0.0' according to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5410 (Pazitos10 comment)

Answer (score 0):

Changed NotebookApp.ip='*' to Changed NotebookApp.ip='0.0.0.0' according to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5410 (Pazitos10 comment)